# Clone in Mac opens Gitbox not Github for mac

Tags: github, github-for-mac, gitbox

I am not sure if anyone has experienced this, but ever since I downloaded Gitbox from the Mac App Store and I click on "Clone in Mac" from github.com. It launches Gitbox instead of GitHub for Mac. Sure enough when I uninstall Gitbox, clicking on "Clone in Mac" launched GitHub for Mac. What could be causing this? How/where is the association being made and is there a way to change it?

Screenshots to refer to them in my comments to Marvin:

[image: Gitbox Plist Screenshot]

[image: GitHub Plist Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The reason the Gitbox app is launched when you click on the *Clone in Mac* link is because the *Clone in Mac* link (on GitHub) uses the `github-mac://` URL type.  In your case, the Gitbox app registered itself to handle the `github-mac://` URL type *presumably* because you installed it after you installed GitHub for Mac.

You can verify the URL type that each application uses by opening their respective `Info.plist` files and searching for the `CFBundleURLTypes` key. The locations for both the `.plist` files are:

```
/Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/Info.plist
/Applications/Gitbox.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Please note that the file paths may be off for Gitbox as I don't actually have it installed and thus can't verify. Also note that if you encounter either `.plist` file in binary format, use the following commands to convert them as needed:

From binary to XML:

```
plutil -convert xml1 some_file.plist
```

From XML to binary:

```
plutil -convert binary1 some_other_file.plist
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Marvin. I've uploaded 2 screenshot of each program's Plist. Your explanation while straight forward and clear, it wasn't applicable to my case. Hopefully these screenshots can shed some light on what else I can try? Thanks again!